# Grid icons html template

Tags: html, css, templates, icons

I wanna build a web application that its main interface contains a list of icons in a grid layout. The best example I know is Icloud as you can see below.

[Icloud interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzxR4.png)

I'm not good at coding HTML, so where can I find an open-source template like that?

Thanks

Comment: Are you creating it for mobile?

Comment: Check out Bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/ I think it has what you are looking for

Comment: @JulianChan I know Bootstrap, but in this case, I'd like to find a template for saving time

Comment: @KashanShah No, just a web app

Comment: @evp What do you define as "saving time"? Bootstrap saves you tons of time from manually adjusting and designing HTML elements, and easily makes web apps mobile friendly. You need to be more specific here.

Comment: If you want to build web applications, not being good at HTML is not an option.
I suggest that you use any html tag (div, span, ul,li) and the grid layout offered by CSS. For icons, you can use any of the open source icon libraries available. My favourite is font-awesome

Comment: Thanks, @KashanShah. In fact, I know and I can use Bootstrap as I said before. But the problem is not only limited to responsive but also the shadow effects, hover, etc. Because I'm lazy and I wanna just focus on the backend so I'm trying to find a open-source or even premium template to resolve issues for myself.

Answer (score -1):

Indeed, what Julian Chan said: https://getbootstrap.com/ is really helpful in this situation.

Bootstrap used the grid system, it has a good documentation on how it behaves and works.
(https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/ Documentation for the Grid System).

I made a little example for you: https://www.bootply.com/JWzQ2x6ARu with the bootstrap grid system

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      APP ICON 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      APP ICON 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      APP ICON 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      APP ICON 4
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      APP ICON 5
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      APP ICON 6
    </div>
  </div> <!-- End of Row 1 -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      APP ICON 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      APP ICON 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      APP ICON 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      APP ICON 4
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      APP ICON 5
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      APP ICON 6
    </div>
  </div> <!-- End of Row 2 -->
</div>
```

In this scenario I gave the div a class of col-md-2 to replicate the image you linked.

Hope this helps you!
Have a nice day!

Answer (score -1):

Simple implementation:

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
img{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><img alt="" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/industrial-and-construction-2-1/129/132-512.png"></li>
  <li><img alt="" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/industrial-and-construction-2-1/129/132-512.png"></li>
  <li><img alt="" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/industrial-and-construction-2-1/129/132-512.png"></li>
  <li><img alt="" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/industrial-and-construction-2-1/129/132-512.png"></li>
  <li><img alt="" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/industrial-and-construction-2-1/129/132-512.png"></li>
  <li><img alt="" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/industrial-and-construction-2-1/129/132-512.png"></li>
<li><img alt="" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/industrial-and-construction-2-1/129/132-512.png"></li>
<li><img alt="" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/industrial-and-construction-2-1/129/132-512.png"></li>
</ul>
```